# Module doesn't output anything in SocialEngine

Tags: php, module, socialengine

I have created SocialEngine default module: created, uploaded.
it shows in Layout Editor but when I dragged and dropped it to the page, it doesn't show anything while the controller has code:

```
class Likecounter_IndexController extends Core_Controller_Action_Standard
{
  public function indexAction()
  {
    $this->view->someVar = 'someVal';
  }
}
```

and the view has code:

```
Index for skeleton module: Likecounter

someVar : <?php echo $this->someVar ?>
```

As I said it has the default code and nothing is wrong with the code.

I have asked a question same as this before, but that one was widget that was working correctly, but this one(module) doesn't output anything.

What's your guess about it? How can I fix it?

thanks

Comment: is your module enabled?

Comment: Yes I have enabled after installing.

Comment: provide the link where I can check.

Comment: just need to enter ur module name it will take index controller and action by default coz its defines as index.